# How to fetch all repositories with specific topic, using GitHub GraphQL API?

Tags: api, github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I am trying to fetch all my repositories that contain topic "portfolio" using Github GraphQL API.

For now, I found only how to fetch **all repos on github with a specific topic**, like so :

```
{
  search(type: REPOSITORY, query: "topic: portfolio", last: 50) {
    repos: edges {
      repo: node {
        ... on Repository {
          url
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I know how to fetch **all repos for a specific user**, like so:

```
{
  user(login: "VitFL") {
    repositories(last: 50) {
      repos: nodes {
        url
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I have no idea how to combine those queries, so I could receive **all repos with topic "portfolio" for a specific user**.

Does anyone know how to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1):

Using `search()`, a `user` argument can be added to the `query` value.

Also, the whitespace after the colon should be removed, i.e. `topic: portfolio` -> `topic:portfolio`. You will notice far more results with this change.

```
{
  search(type: REPOSITORY, query: "user:VitFL topic:portfolio", last: 50) {
    repos: edges {
      repo: node {
        ... on Repository {
          url
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```