# How to clone/access all repos with keys words of a Github Orgnization?

Tags: github

I am trying to clone/access all repos with keywords (Ex: ILOVECS) of an organization. There are around 4k repos in total in the organization. Is there a way to only clone repos with keywords that I want?

My ultimate goal is to collect all changes(Ex: how many lines deleted/added) of all commits from all repos by git -log, and store them in a csv file. Is there a better way to access these repos rather than clone them all?

Comment: This is a question about GitHub, not about Git. (How to clone a repository is a question about Git, but this is fundamentally about iterating over all repositories in an organization, and Git doesn't have "organizations" in the first place.) I updated your tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GitHub GraphQL API v4](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql) for:

- [listing repositories in an organization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52749607/6309)
- with a `search(query ...)` [including topics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62214369/6309), to filter by topic.

But once you have that list, [most of the stats I know of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1486819/6309) (involving *every* commit) are better addressed with a local clone.

Even [`mergestat/mergestat`](https://github.com/mergestat/mergestat) would clone the repository in a local temp folder before executing its SQL-like query.